# ios - struggling to populate a UITableView from an NSArray

Tags: ios, ios5

I have this code:

```
@interface MyBusinessesController : UIViewController
{
    NSDictionary *businesses;
    NSArray *items_array;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *messageLabel;
- (IBAction)plan:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *itemList;

@end
```

and I set the UITableView and the NSArray in the header area of the .m file.  Then I have a remote server call and get back JSON.  I get the JSON data into an array like this:

```
items_array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Then I loop through the items like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<= items_array.count - 1; i++) 
{
  NSDictionary *dict = [items_array objectAtIndex:i];

  NSString *item_title = [dict objectForKey:@"item_title"];
  NSString *item_id = [dict objectForKey:@"item_id"];
  ...
```

and then I would like to add it as a row in my UITableView, but I am struggling with how to do it now.

What I would want is to display the item_title to the user, and when the user presses the title that I would be able to know how to get the item_id of that item_title.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through the array and pulling out the string values you can let the data source methods for UITableView handle this. So in cellForRowAtIndexPath method you would index your items_array with the index path as such:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

Then you would pull the strings out of the dictionary like you did in the loop and set the title for the cell to the string. For selecting the cell, you can write your code in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Here is an example from a project I was working on:

```
    #pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [items_array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault)
                                                   reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"item_name"];

    return cell;
}
```

The first method specifies the number of sections you want in your table. If you want a very simple table this will be 1. The second method is the number of rows. This will be the number of items in your items_array so: `[items_array count]`. The third method creates a cell based on the index. It will go from section 0 to the number of sections you specify and from row 0 to number of rows per section you specify. So now instead of looping you can just index out your array. `[indexPath section]` gives the section number and `[indexPath row]` gives the row number.

*I know I should probably dequeue cells before making new ones but my array is very small.

Comment: thanks..just to be clear...right after I get the array created, I should use line you suggest to create a dictionary?  I am not too clear on how to use it since as I understand, dictionary is not ordered, and the reason I wanted to use the array is because it is ordered....sorry, still confused.

Comment: The order of the dictionary should be the same as the order of your arrays if you are using the loop in your question. What you need to do is add the datasource and delegate protocols in your header file like @fzwo said. If you are using a UITableViewController, this will already be done for you and the methods you need will be in the implementation. If you use a UIViewController, you need to write the methods for the data source and delegate.

Comment: I was going to take out the loop. Also now my header declaration looks like this @ interface MyBusinessesController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> ..I changed it thanks to fzwo suggestion.

Comment: I would advise you to disregard this answer for now. Your problems are much more fundamental, and this kind of premature optimization will only distract you (not to mention that the posted code doesn't work).

Comment: Yes, you can remove the loop since you will be using the index of the row. What you need to do now is in your .m file add the methods for UITableViewDataSource. I will add a quick link to my answer with a sample file.

Comment: @fzwo how is my code incorrect? He can use the indexPath and the it's row property to index out his array and use that to create a cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: @SiddharthDhingra thank you - I already had the numberOfSectionsInTableView and the numberOfRowsInSection methods as you have it since I was doing other tutorials.  And the cellForRowAtIndexPath is the one I am confused with....reading it now so I can understand it.

Comment: @SiddharthDhingra I'm sorry, I misread. Apologies for the accusation. Still, the OP needs some more basic help before we can get to the finer points.

Comment: Btw, what is the "CommitteeCell" in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Also I think I got my 3 mothods to be how you have in your code. What exactly should I do after I get my array like this  items_array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];  ...I mean, what is the next step to take?

Comment: @GeekedOut That's just a name. Cells can be reused, see my comment about finer points in my answer. The book I mention explains it very nicely, and not just how, but also why. You can ignore it for now, and just use any name you want.

Comment: That's alright. I agree that the OP needed more basic help, sorry for any confusion. The tutorial provided by @detray83 is very good to learn the basics of UITableView.

Comment: If you have implemented your methods, you just tell your tableView to reloadData, and that's it. Stick this line into your new methods: `NSLog(@"CellForRowAtIndexPath was called")` to see if they're called.

Comment: Thank you - but how do I tell the data to be reloaded? :)

Comment: @SiddharthDhingra I just tried to run it and it ran, but the table didnt get populated with items....investigating it now :)

Comment: did you set the dataSource of table to self? tableView.dataSource = self.

Comment: @SiddharthDhingra in which part of the code? I don't think I did...where should I do it?

Comment: @SiddharthDhingra I put some debug statements in there, and the methods are not being called.

Comment: Do this in the viewDidLoad method of your code. When your view loads, the table view should know that its dataSource is the view controller itself. In the same method load your data into your array from the JSON. Then you would call the reloadData on the table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14771/discussion-between-geekedout-and-siddharth-dhingra)

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the required methods in the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, and set the `dataSource` property of the tableView to `self`.

Accordingly, implement the appropriate `UITableViewDelegate` methods, and set the `delegate` property of your tableView to `self`.

See the documentation for details on which methods are required, and which optional methods you might want to implement.

Don't forget to advertise in your `.h` file that your Class conforms to both protocols:

```
@interface MyBusinessesController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

You can make the tableView refresh its content by calling `[itemList reloadData]`.

Comment: thanks, I added interface MyBusinessesController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> to my .h declaration. But I am still confused on which method I need to implement in my .m file and how it should be called....sorry - still learning :)

Comment: Have a look at Apple's Documentation - you'll find it in the Organizer Window in Xcode. The documentation for `UITableViewDataSource` will tell you there are two required methods. Implement these, set `itemList.delegate = self;`, call `[itemList reloadData]`, and you will see your TableView display stuff. For handling which cells have been touched, look in the `UITableViewDelegate` documentation, but you should first get to the point where it actually displays something.

Comment: is there an apple docs tutorial for this? Do you have the link? I keep googling and seeing other StackOverflow questions :) btw, the call to [itemList reloadData] - that is in my function where I create the array, right? I looked at some tutorials today, and I am confused about after I get the array, what to call next, i.e, the logical steps I need to take.

Comment: would it be possible if you posted more code samples so I can see how to implement the methods, and what calls I need to make once I create the array?

Comment: It works like this: You create a tableView, and you tell it: This (me) is your DataSource. Whenever you call `reloadData`, and whenever the tableView scrolls new cells into view, it is going to ask its dataSource: "Hey, can you give me the cell for row 5?", etc. - these methods are declared in UITableViewDataSource, and you will have to implement them. Just search the docs (in the Organizer window) for UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: I'm going to bed now, so won't be able to help you further. Siddarth's answer provides a very basic skeleton for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (the method I talked about in the comment above), which should get you started. There are finer points about cell management once your table gets longer, and if you plan on doing more iOS development, do yourself a favor and get a good book. I recommend *iOS Programming - The Big Nerd Ranch Guide*. Not cheap, but very good. Easy to read, nice examples, provides a lot of insight you won't always find here. I've bought two editions for myself; helped me lots.

Answer (score 2):

Table views work differently to what you appear to be used. You don't loop over your data and fill the table. Instead, you set yourself as table's delegate and then the table will ask you:"How much data do you have, what data do you want at row 5" and so on.

I'd really suggest you go over this great tutorial here:
http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-uitableview-tutorial.html